# LaTeX packages do not affect bibliography file

Tags: biblatex, biber, input-encodings

Sorry if this is an already answered question, but I searched for hours through the Internet without success.

It seems like the packages used in my `main.tex` file do not affect my `.bib` file, in fact I get errors like

```
undefined inputenc `utf8` character encoding
```

while in the main file I use succesfully the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Moreover, I saw that even comments don't work inside the bibliography.

Is there something I'm missing?

Sorry but I'm pretty new to LaTeX and thanks in advance for your time!

EDIT:

These are the packages concerning language and encoding settings included in the main file:

```
% Language and encoding
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, english, italian]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel} 

% Bibliography
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
```

If it could be of any help, this is my bibliography:

```
@book{jkz:fcl,
    author = "Jon Kabat-Zinn",
    title  = "Full Catastrophe Living",
    date   = "1990"
}

@online{headspace:appleStore,
    title        = {Headspace: Guided Meditation and Mindfulness sull'App Store},
    date         = {2016},
    organization = {Headspace meditation limited \© Headspace Inc},
    url          = {https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/headspace-guided-meditation/id493145008?mt=8}
}

@online{headspace:playStore,
    title        = {Headspace - meditation - App Android su Google Play},
    date         = {2016},
    organization = {Headspace meditation limited \© Headspace Inc},
    url          = {https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getsomeheadspace.android&hl=it}
}

@online{wildflowers:site,
    title        = "Our Innovative Technology",
    date         = "2016",
    organization = "Mobio Interactive",
    url          = "http://www.wildflowersmindfulness.com/our-technology"
}

@book{taichi:meditazione,
    author = "Da Liu",
    title  = "Tai Chi Chuan e Meditazione",
    date   = "1988"
}

@book{taichi:struttura,
    author = "Mantak Chia \& Juan Li",
    title  = "La Struttura Interna del Tai Chi",
    date   = "1998"
}

@book{taichi:classici,
    author = "Waysun Liao",
    title  = "I Classici del T'ai Chi",
    date   = "1996"
}

@online{taichi:youtube,
    title        = "Tai Chi Ball Workout for Beginners by David-Dorian Ross (YMAA)",
    date         = "2015",
    organization = "Youtube",
    author       = "David-Dorian Ross",
    url          = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_V7dXrQUoNo"
}

@book{mindfulness:cervello,
    author = "Daniel J. Siegel",
    title  = "Mindfulness e cervello",
    date   = "2009"
}

@book{mindfulness:metodo,
    author = "Mark Williams, Danny Penman",
    title  = "Metodo Mindfulness",
    date   = "2016"
}

@online{pdollar:site,
    title        = "\$P Point-Cloud Recognizer",
    date         = "2016",
    organization = "University of Washington",
    author       = "Jacob O. Wobbrock",
    url          = "http://depts.washington.edu/madlab/proj/dollar/pdollar.html"
}

@online{pdollar:publication,
    title        = "Gestures as Point Clouds: A \$P Recognizer for User Interface Prototypes",
    date         = "2012",
    author       = "J.O. Wobbrock, L. Anthony, R.-D. Vatavu",
    url          = "http://faculty.washington.edu/wobbrock/pubs/icmi-12.pdf"
}

@online{taichiBegginers:youtube,
    title        = "10 Simple Tai Chi Exercises in 10 Minutes - Daily Tai Chi for Beginners",
    date         = "2016",
    organization = "Youtube",
    author       = "Wing Chun Kid - Tai Chi JKD Kung Fu",
    url          = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYzBbo0462s&index=2&list=PLEFyCSyrcK_eYcVlPEq6_L3hIIpKb4i7-"
}

@online{unity,
    title        = "Unity - Game Engine",
    date         = "2017",
    organization = "Unity3D",
    url          = "https://unity3d.com/"
}
```

I don't know where the errors are precisely, because I always get them at the `\end{document}` element in the main file.

The two errors are:
1. `Undefined control sequence. \end`
2. `Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding 'utf8'. \end`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE, so that we are able to fully understand your problem and help you.

Comment: `bibtex` or `biblatex` + `biber`? `bibtex` does not support UTF8.

Comment: Normally `biblatex` picks up the document encoding and assumes that the `.bib` file has the same encoding (you can explicitly override that, if need be). But not all characters are set up in `inputenc`, sometimes weird unicode symbols like non-breaking spaces confuse TeX. We would need to see an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (please explicitly state the encoding of your files).

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

@Schweinebacke: I'm using biblatex + biber

Comment: @moewe: I added more details to the question, if you want to take a look. Don't hesitate to ask if you need more. Thank you again for your time

Comment: LaTeX does not know a command `\©`. Maybe this should be `©` (without backslash in front) or even `/©`, with slash as a kind of separator. Unfortunately your code is still not an MWE.

Answer (score 3):

The copyright symbols are the problem. Replace them with `\textcopyright{}` and all is fine:

```
@online{headspace:appleStore,
    title        = {Headspace: Guided Meditation and Mindfulness sull'App Store},
    date         = {2016},
    organization = {Headspace meditation limited \textcopyright{} Headspace Inc},
    url          = {https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/headspace-guided-meditation/id493145008?mt=8}
}

@online{headspace:playStore,
    title        = {Headspace - meditation - App Android su Google Play},
    date         = {2016},
    organization = {Headspace meditation limited \textcopyright{} Headspace Inc},
    url          = {https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getsomeheadspace.android&hl=it}
}
```

Or even just ©, without the backslash:

```
@online{headspace:appleStore,
    title        = {Headspace: Guided Meditation and Mindfulness sull'App Store},
    date         = {2016},
    organization = {Headspace meditation limited © Headspace Inc},
    url          = {https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/headspace-guided-meditation/id493145008?mt=8}
}

@online{headspace:playStore,
    title        = {Headspace - meditation - App Android su Google Play},
    date         = {2016},
    organization = {Headspace meditation limited © Headspace Inc},
    url          = {https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getsomeheadspace.android&hl=it}
}
```